# jquery mobile responsive panel: open left and right panels at the same time

Tags: jquery-mobile, panel, responsive

For jquery mobile responsive panel on a big wide screen, left and right panels should be allowed to be opened at the same time. But currently 1.4.5, only one panel can stay open. opening one panel will close the other. Obviously this is not ideal. There is a way to keep both panels open at the same time for responsive panel?

```
<div class="ui-page ui-responsive-panel">

   <div class="ui-panel" data-position="left">

   </div>

   <div class="ui-panel" data-position="right">

   </div>
</div>
```